# High school physics - friction on inclined plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

I'm using this problem as an example - (see Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCxYoVE2kc8)). Essentially there is a mass of 2kg on an inclined plane of $30^o$ and it is connected via a frictionless pulley to a hanging mass of 6 kg. The coefficient of friction on the inclined plane is $u=0.13$
Using $F=ma$ on the system$ and assuming the free hanging mass moves downward gives the following equation:

$$\begin{align*}
-F_f -m_1g\sin \theta +m_2g &=(m_1+m_2)a \\
-um_1g\cos \theta -m_1g\sin \theta +m_2g &=(m_1+m_2)a 
\end{align*}
$$
Which is fine, you end up the solution as in the video. I'm not asking how to solve for the acceleration.

My problem is if I assume that the hanging mass accelerates upward instead and then write the equations and that friction is going to appose the direction of acceleration, I come up with:
$$\begin{align*}
-F_f +m_1g\sin \theta -m_2g &=(m_1+m_2)a \\
-um_1g\cos \theta +m_1g\sin \theta -m_2g &=(m_1+m_2)a 
\end{align*}
$$

So all the forces change sign except for Friction, but you'll **obviously end up with a different and incorrect answer**. You do end up with a negative acceleration, which indicates your initial assumption was incorrect, but that means you have to adjust the equation and resolve. Is there an easier way to solve this if you assume the acceleration is upwards?

Really, my question is how to handle the direction of friction, when you assumed the direction of acceleration incorrectly?

This came about in helping my daughter with her high school physics, so I have to explain it to her

Comment: Why to use the case where 6kg block accelerates upward whereas the other block is of only 2 kg...Please visualize there is 0% chance of block 6kg accelerating upwards.   PHYSICS IS COMPLETELY VISUALIZATION SUPPORTED BY THEOREMS.

Comment: But I appreciate you thought the other way round as well...I like the way you justified it

Comment: @Aritra In this question it may be fairly obvious, but it isn't always that way. For someone just learning physics they may not realize the impact of assuming the acceleration in the wrong direction.

Comment: The actual answer is not in the choice of the direction of acceleration. Rather, it is in the choice of the direction of the velocity (which will coincide with the choice of acceleration here because you are starting at rest), because it is this that determines which direction friction will be in. Why don't you ask her to ignore friction and use the acceleration from there to determine which direction the friction should be applied? That is how we would usually deal with this teaching problem anyway.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Yes, you're correct about it corresponding to the velocity. Thank you for the idea. Will solving the frictionless case always work? I have seen a more involved example with each mass on it's own inclined plane (each with different coefficients of friction).

Comment: You should only need to resort to turning off friction if something is momentarily at rest, since motion would already inform you which direction friction would act, but then yes, if it is at rest, the frictionless acceleration direction will be the thing that friction opposes.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent you are right i support your statement

Answer (score 1):

[image]

First, you set up an **intrinsic** coordinate system where the axis is what is in red (yes, it bends). You consider as positive x+ the direction shown in the picture, but you could consider as positive the opposite.

Then, if you are willing to assume that the string does not deform and keeps tight, the acceleration is equal for both bodies (if you wanted a more sophisticated argument of why the accelerations are equal you would need to write the ligature equations). Third, you write the equations for each body which are:

$$-u_d m_1 g cos \theta - m_1 g sin \theta +T = m1 a$$
$$-T +m_2 g = m_2 a$$

Now, replace with the values and assume $g=10 m/s$. Then $T = 24.18 N$ and $a = 5.96 m/s$. But how did I know that the sign for friction force was correct? Since I know that it's in the opposite direction of the accel the body would have without it's existence, and by intuition I know that $m_1$ will move upwards, then the friction aims downwards. But if you can't figure out the correct direction just guess it and solve the equations. If you reach at the conclusion that the direction of the friction is not opposite to the acceleration of the body with respect to the surface where it moves, you've got a contradiction so the direction must be opposite.

BTW, you shouldn't assume that friction is $u_d mg cos \theta$. First you should check if the bodies will move, for that you make $a=0$ and leave friction force as unknown. Solve for it and you check if friction is less that $u_e mg cos \theta$. If that happens, the body will stay still, otherwise will move with a friction force equal to $u_d mg cos \theta$. But I guess you don't have $u_e$ so in this case lie to yourself and assume the bodies will move.

Comment: In their high-school physics they don't  cover static friction or at least they haven't yet. In the solutions provided by their teacher and in the book, they aren't checking for equilibrium.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

you obtain those equations:

**the free hanging mass moves downward**

$$ m_1\,a_1+F_\mu+m_1\,g\,\sin(\theta)-T=0\\
m_2\,a_2-m_2\,g+T=0\\
a_1=a_2$$

**the free hanging mass moves upward**

$$ -m_1\,a_1-F_\mu+m_1\,g\,\sin(\theta)-T=0\\
-m_2\,a_2-m_2\,g+T=0\\
a_1=a_2$$

where $~F_\mu=\mu\,m_1\,g\,\cos(\theta)~$

thus

case I

$$a_1\approx 5.9\quad,T\approx 24$$

case II

$$a_1\approx -6.4 \quad,T\approx 20$$

Comment: So how do you resolve the discrepancy between the two solutions?

Comment: My equation are correct, the discrepancy is due to the force $~m_1\,g\,\sin(\theta)$